# C++ program to convert string to numeric digits

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function that converts input words to numeric digits like a mobile numpad. It is for an assignment. I cannot use cstring or character arrays.

Can someone please identify and correct the error in my code? It currently gives the error: `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]`.

I am not using any pointer variables. I do have used the `strlen()` function to determine the exact place of a character in a string. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void Letter_correspondence();

int main()
{
    Letter_correspondence();
    return 0;
}

void Letter_correspondence()
{

    cout<<"Enter the letters of the word you want to convert to numbers: ";
    char a[]="Hello";
    char b[]="world";
    int len=strlen(a);
    int lenb=strlen(b);
    int n;
    int l=a[n];
    for (n=0;n<=7;n++)
    {
        while (n<=len)
        {
            if (l=="a"||l=="b"||l=="c")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"2";

            }
            else if (l=="d"||l=="e"||l=="f")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"3";
            }
            else if (l=="g"||l=="h"||l=="i")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"4";
            }
            else if (l=="j"||l=="k"||l=="l")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"5";
            }
            else if (l=="m"||l=="n"||l=="o")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"6";
            }
            else if (l=="p"||l=="q"||l=="r"||l=="s")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"7";
            }
            else if (l=="t"||l=="u"||l=="v")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"8";
            }
            else if (l=="w"||l=="x"||l=="y"||l=="z")
            {
                if (n==2)
                {
                    cout<<"-";
                }
                cout<<"9";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace `l=="a"` with `l=='a'`, etc. (and move `int l` inside the for-loop)

Comment: side note : int n;
    int l=a[n]; n is not initalized

Comment: *"It currently gives the error iso C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]. I am not using any pointer variables."* Yes, you are using pointers. That's what those string literals that you're using everywhere decay into. The `int n; int l=a[n];` part is nonsense. I kind of see what you're trying to do, but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: *I cannot use cstring or character arrays.* -- You are using character arrays: `char a[]="Hello";`  I don't understand why teachers force students to dumb-down their programs to the point of ridiculousness.

Comment: *I do have used the strlen() function to determine the exact place of a character in a string.*  contradicts *I cannot use cstring or character arrays*. Chances are that you are supposed to read and process (convert to number) a single `char` at a time. Also note that all those `if (n==2) { cout<<"-"; }` can be replaced by a *single one* before the`if`s.

Comment: can someone please correct the code? as a whole

Comment: @rustyx i tried what you said but now it gives this error : main.cpp:30:36: warning: missing terminating ' character
             if (l=='a'||l=='b'||l=='c)

Comment: @Blaze not to be rude or anything id appreciate help rather than criticism. Im a complete newbie to coding.

Comment: @Bob__ yeah ik but i copy pasted and edited the contents of the while loops and the if's came along so i kind of stuck to it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah ikr. My first thought was to use a 2d array to form a table and refer to the corresponding digits

Comment: @HassanIftikhar sorry, I didn't mean to be condescending. But it's hard to help with this code because it's unclear what it's supposed to do. There's a loop in a loop construction with no explanation what it does (or should do). There are even some parts such as `char b[]="world";` that aren't used at all. I don't know what the point of the `if (n==2)` is and there's no explanation. Lots of things about this code makes it seem like you didn't use language constructs as they are explained in the course material, but just randomly tried some stuff and hoped for the best.

Comment: I posted an answer and I hope it helps you, but I had to make some assumptions about what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this right, you're trying to map characters to different ones and print them. You said you cannot use cstring or character arrays, but you do that here:

```
char a[]="Hello";
char b[]="world";
```

Instead, I would just use `std::string`:

```
std::string a = "Hello";
```

You can then iterate through it using a range-based for loop. The best way to print your string would probably be using a `switch`statement:

```
for (char &c : a)
    {
        switch (tolower(c)) {
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
            std::cout << 2;
            break;

        case 'd':
        case 'e':
        case 'f':
            std::cout << 3;
            break;

        case 'g':
        case 'h':
        case 'i':
            std::cout << 4;
            break;

        case 'j':
        case 'k':
        case 'l':
            std::cout << 5;
            break;

        case 'm':
        case 'n':
        case 'o':
            std::cout << 6;
            break;

        case 'p':
        case 'q':
        case 'r':
        case 's':
            std::cout << 7;
            break;

        case 't':
        case 'u':
        case 'v':
            std::cout << 8;
            break;

        case 'w':
        case 'x':
        case 'y':
        case 'z':
            std::cout << 9;
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << c;
        }
    }
```

---

If you're using an old version of C++ that doesn't support range based for loops, change this

```
for (char &c : a)
    {
        switch (tolower(c)) {
```

To this

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        switch (tolower(a[i])) {
```

And `std::cout << c;` to `std::cout << a[i];`.

Comment: tysm. When i do apply this it now gives this error: 23 16 [Error] range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

Comment: @HassanIftikhar I made an edit to include a version with a classic `for` loop.

Comment: @HassanIftikhar Why are you using a version of C++ that is **over 20 years old**?